# Report Viewer - convert any 0 value to display blank or null value

Tags: c#, reportviewer

How do I make any 0 value display blank or null?
Can I do a condition expression in report viewer perhaps

Update: here is what I have tried

```
=IIf(FormatNumber(Fields!totalnetamaount.Value, 2) is 0, "", FormatNumber(Fields!totalnetamaount.Value, 2))
```

It threw the exception

> Error 1   The Value expression for the textrun
>   ‘totalnetamaount.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error:
>   [BC30020] 'Is' operator does not accept operands of type 'Integer'.
>   Operands must be reference or nullable
>   types.

Comment: @EmpereurAiman updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your "is" with "=". 
Modify your condition as follows,

```
=IIf(FormatNumber(Fields!totalnetamaount.Value, 2)=0, "", FormatNumber(Fields!totalnetamaount.Value, 2))
```

Comment: Thank you @Mahe. This is very helpful. For all who down-voted without any reason should be ashamed of themselves.